# How do i break the upload to s3 if values are not getting uploaded to the server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, server

I have a code to upload the data to the server and due to any condition if few values are not uploaded to the server I want the later code which uploads data to s3 also to upload the same value. Ex : imagine i am uploading [1,2,3,4,5,6] to the server from lambda for some reason 2,3 didn't get uploaded. Instead of the full list getting uploaded to s3 i want the same values to get uploaded ad server. how do I do that?

```
if df.shape[0] > 0: 
 for i in range(len(df)):
  values = f"{df['RMA'][i]},. 
 {df['serial_number'][i]},. 
 {df['code_type'][i]},{df['date_opened'][i]},{df['created_by'][i]},{df['rma_customer'][i]},{df['acacia_component_pn'][i]},{df['component_engineer'][i]},{df['product_engineer'][i]},{df['qty'][i]},{df['test_process'][i]},{df['reference'][i]},{df['component_supplier_name'][i]},{df['component_supplier_pn'][i]},{df['component_supplier_date_code'][i]},\ {df['component_supplier_lot_code'][i]},{df['severity_class'][i]},{df['component_failure_detail'][i]},{df['supplier_RMA'][i]},{df['fa_owner'][i]},{df['AW_ref_bill'][i]},{df['component_shipped_to_supplier'][i]},{df['component_received_by_supplier'][i]},{df['supplier_fa_received'][i]},{df['is_active'][i]},{df['cfar_open_date'][i]},{df['cfar_closed_date'][i]},{df['Unit_Fault_Diagnosis'][i]}"  

 response = client.service.fn_Log("279", "xyz", "xyz", "RMA", "xyz", "1", parameters, values, ",") 
if (response.Message != None) | (response.Result != 'True'): logger.error(i) logger.error(values) logger.error(response)
```

this is the code to upload to the server and for uploading to s3 ill directly upload

`upload_to_s3(df, 'xyz/xyz.csv')`

Comment: Please Edit your answer and format the code properly. It is difficult to understand at the moment.

Comment: Tried editting if it's clear can you kindly help me

Comment: That is still not valid Python. Please include the newlines and indents.

Comment: Can you please redefine the question in a structured way with some examples? It will help people understand the question better and answer it. Thanks @Manav